# NSCalendar Find Saturday and Sunday of Current Month

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am working on project where I want to integrate NSCalendar functionality in my app. Hence I googled and I found [this](http://super-mak.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-create-calendar-in-iphone-and.html) solution. It give me all months in the year and also I can select particular date. that's fine. But I wanted to disable all saturdays and sundays of every month somehow I tried to do it but when I tap previous month or next month it changes the selection. I have gone through almost all stackoverflow questions But I didn't find proper way to do it.
    I request you to all Is there any flexible solution on this where I can disable weekends and any particular date. The flow should be like this:

1. Run the application current month is display and all sat & sun disabled.
2. When tap on next month or previous month, the respective sat & sun should be disable as per that month.
3. Functionality for any particular date that I want to disable.

Comment: Can you please add some code to it so that we are able to better understand the problem at hand

Comment: I want complete new solution on that because whatever code I have written is not working perfectly.

Comment: It will be better that you share the code because that will give us the hint what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i updated the files and i created an array of disabled days please check the code form here

RootViewController.m file
http://shorttext.com/l7iKEdf

RootViewController.h file
http://shorttext.com/lFaath

just replace these files with the original files from the link you provided
you will find that i added a disabledDays NSMutableArray add any integers to it to it
like following 0 = sat 6 = friday
and that day will be disabled

Comment: if it was a satisfying answer, please dont forget to accept :)

Comment: Nice work. One line I have changed in your code  [disabledDays addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]; Instead of put 2 I used 1 because using 2 it give me monday ans saturday and using 1 gives me saturday and sunday. but now one new bug raised that is for september and december 2012 it disable sunday and monday not saturday and sunday. Just wanted to inform you what is this happening.

Comment: Yes i saw the bug, ok i temporarily fixed it by doing the following
find the line     int weekOfDayAcc = weekDay;
and add the following after it     if(weekOfDayAcc == 7)
        weekOfDayAcc = 0;
this fixes the following issue, please dont forget to test it since i didnt have time to optimize or fully test the solution :)

Comment: How can we disable next year all date means I want to show only current year date active.