# How to customize the calendar in iphone without using UIDatepicker in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

Hello I want to customize the calendar.  The Calendar look like monthly calendar.  How can be done this.
Any one Help me

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you trying to do?  Need more information for this question to be considered useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is not the answer but I can suggest you what I did in my project.
This calendar API has exactly the same appearance as iPhone in-bult calendar

You can integrate [Kal Project available on github](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

Steps to integrate the project has been given over there.

You can also refer to [this project](http://super-mak.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-create-calendar-in-iphone-and.html) which is quite simpler & have only 2 files to integrate in project.

Also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845688/nscalendar-find-saturday-and-sunday-of-current-month) u will find steps to disable the particular dates like weekends or specific dates